# Access repository from a Hangfire job to send emails weekly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, hangfire

I'm currently setting up a recurring job with Hangfire which needs to send an email to every ApplicationUser of the application every day.

I already managed to put my connection string and access the Dashboard, and the Hangfire tables have correctly been added to my database.

The issue is I can't manage to access my AccountRepository to run a method the function which will send the mails, as there is no AccountRepository instance available.

What is the cleanest way to access to my repository without doing everything from the Startup class? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? A hangfire job should be self contained, but there's no reason it can't access other resources, provided these can be instantiated in a sane manner. Are you using an IoC container?

Comment: making the question more clear would help a lot! maybe using Dependency injection would help

Comment: I'm kind of struggling to explain my problem as I'm not english native sorry, I'm looking at dependency injection and it seems it's what I need thanks. For now I can't manage to make it work but I'll go further into it.